# ScrollView scrolls when content fits on screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm having an issue where I have a ScrollView content inside of it. In the event that the content doesn't all fit on screen, I want it to scroll. However, if it all fits I don't want it to scroll.

As is, the scrollviewer scrolls quite a bit and all the content can be scrolled way off screen.

How does one get the scrollview to not scroll when all the content fits on the screen?

`<ScrollView
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/productImageView"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/detailsScrollView"
        android:paddingRight="24dp"
        android:paddingLeft="24dp"
        android:clipChildren="true"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:measureAllChildren="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:paddingTop="24dp"
            android:paddingBottom="24dp">
            <TextView
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/patternTitleTextView" />
            <TextView
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/designerNameTextView"
                android:textColor="@color/default_gray" />
            <TextView
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/descriptionTextView"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:minLines="200"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                android:scrollHorizontally="false"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:ellipsize="none" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>`

Comment: Could you post your entire layout file, rather than just the scroll view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in my case was with one of the TextViews.

```
 <TextView
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/descriptionTextView"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:minLines="200"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                android:scrollHorizontally="false"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:ellipsize="none" />
```

I shouldn't have set minLines or set the layout_weight. After removing those two things  the scrollview did exactly what I expected it to.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to create a custom ScrollView:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.ScrollView;

public class CustomScrollView extends ScrollView {

    private boolean enableScrolling = true;

    public boolean isEnableScrolling() {
        return enableScrolling;
    }

    public void setEnableScrolling(boolean enableScrolling) {
        this.enableScrolling = enableScrolling;
    }

    public CustomScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public CustomScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomScrollView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

        if (isEnableScrolling()) {
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can do something similar to this in your code:

```
CustomScrollView myScrollView = (CustomScrollView) findViewById(R.id.myScroll);
myScrollView.setEnableScrolling(false); // disable scrolling
myScrollView.setEnableScrolling(true); // enable scrolling
```

Of course, it will be up to you to decide when exactly you need to enable/disable scrolling.